# GCP Airflow connection by using secret manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to add Airflow connection for GCP cloud(SA key should be fetched from secret manager) but in my Airflow UI(version 2.1.4) I couldn't find option for adding by using secret manager. Is it because of version problem?

[image]

If so can we add the airflow connection (by using secret manager) via command line (gcloud) or via programmatically to add it.

I tried via command line but it throws below error:

```
gcloud composer environments run project_id --location europe-west2 connections add --  edw_test    --conn-type=google_cloud_platform    --conn-extra '{"extra__google_cloud_platform__project": "proejct", "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_secret_name": "test_edw","extra__google_cloud_platform__scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"}'
kubeconfig entry generated
Unable to connect to the server i/o timeout
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) kubectl returned non-zero status code.
```

Comment: I have upgraded both composer and airflow version which paved the way for creating the airflow connection by keeping the keys in secret manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded both composer and airflow version which paved the way for creating the airflow connection by keeping the keys in secret manager

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by configuring airflow to use Secret Manager as a secrets backend. For this to work, however, the service account you use to access the backend needs to have permission to access secrets.

### Secrets Backend

For example, you can set the value directly in `airflow.cfg`:

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend
```

Via environment variable:

```
export AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND=airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend
```

### Creating Connection

Then you can create a secret directly in Secret Manager. If you have configured your Airflow instance to use Secret Manager as the secrets backend, it will pick up any secrets that have the correct prefix.
The default prefixes are:

- `airflow-connections`
- `airflow-variables`
- `airflow-config`

In your case, you would create a secret named `airflow-connections-edw_test`, and set the value to `google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=project&extra__google_cloud_platform__key_secret_name=test_edw&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform`

Note that the parameters have to be url encoded.

More info:

- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/secrets-backends/google-cloud-secret-manager-backend.html#enabling-the-secret-backend
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html